# How to clear cookies in angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, session-cookies, angular-cookies

Currently am using angulajs app.

I want to store some values in cookie. So i used `angular-cookies-min` script for add some values to cookies

I have used this below code for save values to cookie.

```
 $cookieStore.put("userInfo", userInfo);//userInfo is a array with some values.
```

**Now I want to clear the cookie? How can i do it?**

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try this code for delete cookie

```
$cookieStore.remove("userInfo");
```

**EDIT**: Since v1.4 `$cookieStore` has been deprecated (see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)), so from that version on you should use:

```
$cookies.remove("userInfo");
```

Comment: UP : it's now deprecated in angular 1.4, prefer use $cookies.

Comment: $cookies.remove('user'); var cookie = $cookies.get('user'); and I always get the value so what it is removing?

Comment: @AliAdravi : Same problem with me as well.

Comment: you should check the path of the cookie when removing as well:
`$cookies.remove("userInfo", {path: "/"});`

Comment: To clear all cookies, I used this one-liner: `for(var x in $cookies) { $cookies.remove(x); }`

Answer (score 6):

I have found some answer

Option 1

```
delete $cookies["userInfo"]
```

option 2

```
 .controller('LogoutCtrl', ['$scope',  '$cookies', function ($scope,$cookies) {

    $cookies.userInfo = undefined;

}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.forEach($cookies, function (cookie, key) {
    if (key.indexOf('NAV-') > -1) {
         $window.sessionStorage.setItem(key, cookie);
         delete $cookies[key];
    }
 });
```

The above code works for me however 'Resources' tab of Chrome inspection utility continues to show that the cookies are not deleted. I verified that the cookies are indeed deleted by printing them out:

```
console.log('START printing cookies AFTER deleting them');
 angular.forEach($cookies, function (cookie, key) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + $cookies[key] + '\n');
 });
 console.log('DONE printing cookies AFTER deleting them');
```

Hope this helps