# Removing cookies in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I have a problem removing cookies set to a particular domain.

When the cookies were set at say domain, **a.b.io** they were being deleted by this code.

```
$scope.clearStorage = function(){
            $localStorage.$reset();
            var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
            angular.forEach(cookies, function (v, k) {
                $cookies.remove(k);
            });
```

But when I set it to the domain **b.io** it isn't working. Tried to debug the the problem, the value of k is correct but $cookies.remove is simply not removing the cookie.

Comment: Which version you using currently?

Comment: try `$cookies.remove(k,{domain:'b.io'})`

Comment: @RitikSaxena This works! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for delete cookie

```
$cookieStore.remove("userInfo");
```

EDIT: Since v1.4 $cookieStore has been deprecated (see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)), so from that version on you should use:

```
$cookies.remove("userInfo");
```

more details view this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/20988750/7255740